# Retornar ultimo valor de cada dia no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá, tenho seguintes valores no banco de dados:

```
data       -           valor
2019-06-03 7:00        9
2019-06-03 12:00       21
2019-06-03 20:00       28
2019-06-02 8:00        11
2019-06-02 12:30       21
2019-06-02 19:50       27
2019-06-01 8:30        10
2019-06-01 14:00       20
2019-06-01 21:00       29
```

Preciso do úlimo valor de cada dia, no caso o resultado teria de ser o seguinte:

```
data       -           valor
2019-06-03 20:00       28
2019-06-02 19:50       27
2019-06-01 21:00       29
```

Como posso ter este resultado no mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que exista diversas maneiras de fazer essa consulta

Aqui esta um exemplo que fiz e testei

```sql
SELECT data, valor FROM `tabela` where data in (
    SELECT MAX(data) FROM `tabela` GROUP BY date(data)
)
```

Saída

```
2019-06-03 20:00:00 28
2019-06-02 19:50:00 27
2019-06-01 21:00:00 29
```